# Writing a const generic parallel zip using rayon

Tags: rust, rayon

I wish to create an `IndexedParallelIterator<Item = [I::Item; N]>` from an array `[I; N]` where `I: IndexedParallelIterator`. Let's call it `ParConstZip<I, N>`.

As I understand, there's a couple of steps here:

1. Create the corresponding non-parallel `ConstZip<I, N>` iterator (which must implement `ExactSizeIterator` and `DoubleEndedIterator`).
2. Create a `Producer` to split the input and create the `ConstZip<I, N>` iterators.
3. Implement `ParallelIterator` and `IndexedParallelIterator` for `ParConstZip<I, N>` using the `Producer`.

I think I'm alright on points 1. and 2. Specifically, here's the `ConstZip<I, N>` implementation:

```rust
pub struct ConstZip<I, const N: usize>([I; N]);

impl<I, const N: usize> Iterator for ConstZip<I, N>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    type Item = [I::Item; N];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut dst = MaybeUninit::uninit_array();

        for (i, iter) in self.0.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            dst[i] = MaybeUninit::new(iter.next()?);
        }

        // SAFETY: If we reach this point, `dst` has been fully initialized
        unsafe { Some(MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(dst)) }
    }
}

impl<I, const N: usize> ExactSizeIterator for ConstZip<I, N>
where
    I: ExactSizeIterator,
{
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.0.iter().map(|x| x.len()).min().unwrap()
    }
}

impl<I, const N: usize> DoubleEndedIterator for ConstZip<I, N>
where
    I: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut dst = MaybeUninit::uninit_array();

        for (i, iter) in self.0.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            dst[i] = MaybeUninit::new(iter.next_back()?);
        }

        // SAFETY: If we reach this point, `dst` has been fully initialized
        unsafe { Some(MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(dst)) }
    }
}
```

And here's what I believe to be an appropriate producer:

```rust
pub struct ParConstZipProducer<P, const N: usize>([P; N]);

impl<P, const N: usize> Producer for ParConstZipProducer<P, N>
where
    P: Producer,
{
    type Item = [P::Item; N];
    type IntoIter = ConstZip<P::IntoIter, N>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        ConstZip(self.0.map(Producer::into_iter))
    }

    fn split_at(self, index: usize) -> (Self, Self) {
        let mut left_array = MaybeUninit::uninit_array();
        let mut right_array = MaybeUninit::uninit_array();

        for (i, producer) in self.0.into_iter().enumerate() {
            let (left, right) = producer.split_at(index);
            left_array[i] = MaybeUninit::new(left);
            right_array[i] = MaybeUninit::new(right);
        }

        // SAFETY: Arrays are guaranteed to be fully initialised at length `N`
        let left_array = unsafe { MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(left_array) };
        let right_array = unsafe { MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(right_array) };

        (
            ParConstZipProducer(left_array),
            ParConstZipProducer(right_array),
        )
    }
}
```

However, I stumble when it comes to the actual implementation of `IndexedParallelIterator`. Most of it seems to be boilerplate, but the `with_producer` method I cannot figure out how to implement:

```rust
pub struct ParConstZip<I, const N: usize>([I; N]);

impl<I, const N: usize> ParallelIterator for ParConstZip<I, N>
where
    I: IndexedParallelIterator,
{
    type Item = [I::Item; N];

    fn drive_unindexed<C>(self, consumer: C) -> C::Result
    where
        C: UnindexedConsumer<Self::Item>,
    {
        bridge(self, consumer)
    }
}

impl<I, const N: usize> IndexedParallelIterator for ParConstZip<I, N>
where
    I: IndexedParallelIterator,
{
    fn drive<C>(self, consumer: C) -> C::Result
    where
        C: Consumer<Self::Item>,
    {
        bridge(self, consumer)
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.0.iter().map(|x| x.len()).min().unwrap()
    }

    fn with_producer<CB>(self, callback: CB) -> CB::Output
    where
        CB: ProducerCallback<Self::Item>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e218cccff8b4787f46190517e18504f8).

I needed the same thing about a year ago, and asked [a question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/writing-a-parallel-zip-for-a-const-generic-number-of-parallel-iterators/58763) on the users.rust-lang  forum. I got some helpful high-level pointers from one of the authors of `rayon`, but after reading the [rayon plumbing README](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/blob/master/src/iter/plumbing/README.md#what-on-earth-is-producercallback) a number of times both then and now, I have to admit I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: DO NOT override `ExactSizeIterator::len()` like this. The size should be calculated and returned in `Iterator::size_hint()`. You can override `len()` too, if you can provide a more performant implementation (that makes sense here, since you're in a generic context), but **always** implement `Iterator::size_hint()` too.

Comment: Also, just in case, you can replace the unstable `MaybeUninit` methods with their implementation to stay on stable land.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. To be clear, here's another [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7275fb7b453cfb10418bdc0c4bba7b8) with a better `size_hint`/`len`, and with all unsafe code removed. I understand that this is not performant, but I'm mainly interested in the `rayon` specifics.

Comment: You may be overthinking the implementation of `IndexedParallelIterator`. It really ought to be boiler-plate; it's just working around a lifetime limitation with closure syntax. You should be able to copy that and just add fields to the struct for things that the closure will need.

Comment: Thanks, that's also what I gather from the plumbing README, yet I still get lost in the weeds somewhere with all the traits and bounds. If you fancy fleshing it out for an answer a little bit, that would be very appreciated.